# VS2019: Managed C++ assembly linker error LNK1256 while alink signing assembly with key

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, .net-assembly, managed-c++

I've created a Managed C++ library which during build at signing the key failing
with error

---

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1256: ALINK operation failed (80040436) : Error signing assembly -- Unknown error (8013141c)
1>Done building project "CLRCppLib.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

in VS2019
[image]

with project property
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried Framework version 4.8,   4.7.2 as well as 4.6 ;
also values mykey.snk and $(projectdir)mykey.snk and "$(projectdir)mykey.snk"

### but none seems working.
Updated: while same project in VS2015 building fine in other system. there also no Container value is given.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is CORSEC_E_CONTAINER_NOT_FOUND, probably because your /KEYFILE can't be found or is corrupted.  If it is there and looks good with sn.exe then try disabling the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: I've tried Framework version 4.8, 4.7.2 as well as 4.6 ; also values mykey.snk and $(projectdir)mykey.snk and "$(projectdir)mykey.snk"

but none seems working. Updated: while same project in VS2015 building fine in other system. there also no Container value is given. @HansPassant